# Android: Uso básico de Toast.maketext

Tags: java, android, login

Soy muy nuevo en esto y recuerdo que cuando estudié Pascal en la universidad se utilizaba el imprimir por pantalla para verificar las funciones por las que iba pasando un programa en ejecución. Estoy intentando hacer lo mismo con Toast.maketext pero no lo consigo. ¿Es incorrecto este uso de Toast?. Utilizo la activity de Login de android studio:

```
public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private final String mEmail;
    private final String mPassword;

    UserLoginTask(String email, String password) {
        mEmail = email;
        mPassword = password;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        **Toast.makeText(RealLogin.this, "PASÉ POR AQUÍ", 6000).show();**
        for (String credential : DUMMY_CREDENTIALS) {
            String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
            if (pieces[0].equals(mEmail)) {
                // Account exists, return true if the password matches.
                return pieces[1].equals(mPassword);
            }
        }

        // TODO: register the new account here.
        return true;
    }
```

Mil gracias!

EDITO: Muchas gracias a todos por vuestras respuestas, me ha quedado clarísimo :)

Comment: El Toast te genera un dialogo en la pantalla de color negrito  , como si fuera un dialogo es esto lo que queres o queres ver esto por la consola del logcat?

Comment: La clase `UserLoginTask` esta definida en un archivo aparte o dentro de la clase `RealLogin`?

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag como bien lo mencionas para debugging lo ideal es usar la clase Log para desplegar mensajes en el LogCat y no Toast.

Answer (score 3):

En este caso usas un [Asynctask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), es importante comentar que el método [onPostexecute()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)) corre en el hilo principal, despues de la ejecución de `doInBackground()`, por lo tanto **el lugar ideal para mostrar un `Toast` sería precisamente dentro del método [onPostexecute()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result))**

Es importante tomar en cuenta que:

### **el objetivo de un `Toast` es brindar una vista que contiene un pequeño mensaje rápido para el usuario. Mientras que los mensajes del LogCat te puede ayudar a depuración que es precisamente lo que deseas realizar.**

Si deseas imprimir datos o actualizaciones de la información ese recomiendo usar un `Log` (El cual puedes revisar en el **[LogCat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html)**) en lugar de un `Toast`. 
En realidad uno de los objetivos

```
   @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        //Toast.makeText(RealLogin.this, "PASÉ POR AQUÍ", 6000).show();

        Log.i("UserLoginTask", "PASÉ POR AQUÍ"); //* Usa el LogCat.

        for (String credential : DUMMY_CREDENTIALS) {
            String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
            if (pieces[0].equals(mEmail)) {
                // Account exists, return true if the password matches.
                return pieces[1].equals(mPassword);
            }
        }

        // TODO: register the new account here.
        return true;
    }
```

---

Dos apuntes extra que son importantes,

- Si vas a desarrollar en Android es indispensable el uso del  **[LogCat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html)**, además de encontrar rápidamente un problema que sucede en tu aplicación, puedes mostrar mensajes de depuración como lo que deseas realizar.
- El tiempo en el cual sería mostrado un `Toast` únicamente es definido por las constantes:

> [Toast.LENGTH_SHORT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#LENGTH_SHORT) : muestra el texto de la notificación por un
>   corto periodo de tiempo. [Toast.LENGTH_LONG](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#LENGTH_LONG) : muestra el texto de
>   la notificación por un largo periodo de tiempo.

Por lo tanto no puedes definir el tiempo en millisegundos a mostrar:

```
Toast.makeText(RealLogin.this, "PASÉ POR AQUÍ", 6000).show(); //Incorrecto
```

debe ser:

```
Toast.makeText(RealLogin.this, "PASÉ POR AQUÍ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //Correcto
```

o también:

```
Toast.makeText(RealLogin.this, "PASÉ POR AQUÍ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //Correcto
```

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que quieres es imprimir un **log** del progreso de tu aplicación **Android**  en **consola**, puedes utilizar la clase `Log`. Esta clase posee varios métodos para imprimir mensajes en consola. El mas común es el método `i()`. Este método recibe dos parámetros de tipo `String`, el primero es una etiqueta que se utiliza para identificar desde donde se imprime el mensaje y el segundo es el mensaje a imprimir. Este método lo puedes utilizar desde cualquier parte de tu codigo. Por ejemplo:

```
Log.i("MainActivity", "Hola mundo!");
```

Comment: Muchas gracias David, esta forma de hacerlo es muy rápida y cómoda, le voy a dar mucho uso!

Comment: Recuerda dar las gracias de manera constructiva. Como marcando las respuesta como **Aceptada ✔**. Tal como se explica en el **[recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)** del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes mostrar un Toast en otro hilo sino solo en el hilo de la vista.

Asi que si quieres mostrar/modificar/eliminar un elemento de la vista en otro hilo, tienes que hacerlo utilizando el metodo [`Activity#runOnUiThread(Runnable)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)). Pero como no tienes ninguna referencia del Activity, tendrias que enviarle el activity al constructor de la clase:

```
public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private final String mEmail;
    private final String mPassword;
    private final Activity mActivity;

    UserLoginTask(Activity activity, String email, String password) {
        mEmail = email;
        mPassword = password;
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {


        mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(RealLogin.this, "PASÉ POR AQUÍ", 6000).show();
            }
        });
        for (String credential : DUMMY_CREDENTIALS) {
            String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
            if (pieces[0].equals(mEmail)) {
                // Account exists, return true if the password matches.
                return pieces[1].equals(mPassword);
            }
        }

        // TODO: register the new account here.
        return true;
    }
```

Entonces siempre que necesites utilizar la clase, le envias el activity de donde la ejecutas. Por ejemplo al dar clic al boton login en el activity `RealLogin`:

```
loginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View view) {
        new UserLoginTask(RealLogin.this, username, password).execute();
    }
});
```

Pero es bueno decir que la clase `AsyncTask<T,T2,T3>` tiene un metodo llamado [`onPostExecuted()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)) que si se ejecuta en el hilo de la vista una vez terminado el proceso del hilo:

```
public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private final String mEmail;
    private final String mPassword;

    UserLoginTask(String email, String password) {
        mEmail = email;
        mPassword = password;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {


        for (String credential : DUMMY_CREDENTIALS) {
            String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
            if (pieces[0].equals(mEmail)) {
                // Account exists, return true if the password matches.
                return pieces[1].equals(mPassword);
            }
        }

        // TODO: register the new account here.
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
        Toast.makeText(RealLogin.this, "PASÉ POR AQUÍ", 6000).show();
    }
}
```

Y asi ya no necesitarias el Activity para mostrar el Toast, aunque repito: el metodo onPostExecute se ejecuta cuando el metodo `doInBackground` termina

Comment: Lo acabo de probar y funciona. Es exactamente lo que estaba buscando, aunque ahora que veo como se hace quizás me interese más hacerlo como explica David, a través de la clase Log.
Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, he aprendido más de lo que te imaginas con ella :)